# Angular service subscribe callback is not getting called in library component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have created tabs component in library where this component shows tabs and we can change the tabs content or title based on button click which is included in app component.
I have created a service in library to handle this and register subscribe callback in libray component.
But when ever i click the button i am sending data to behaviour subject but subscribe callback is not firing in the library component.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onTabChangeReceived();
  }

    onTabChangeReceived = () => {
       this.caseSelection.onSelectedTab().subscribe(caseSelected => {
       debugger
        console.log('caseSelected =======', caseSelected);
     });
 }
```

The app component i am sending the data like this

```js
 onLockedButtonClicked(event: string) {
         console.log('event is', event);
         this.caseSelectionService.sendSelectedTab(event.toLowerCase().replace(' ', ''))
       }
```

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable,} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LaCasesSelectionService {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('all cases');

  sendSelectedTab(message: string) {
    debugger
    this.subject.next(message);
  }
  onSelectedTab(): Observable<string> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest why this callback is not firing

Comment: Is any diference when you create function like this `onTabChangeReceived()  {` instaed of `onTabChangeReceived = () => {`?

Answer (score 0):

I created a stackblitz with the above code and it appears to be working for me. (I'm getting the log messages.)

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-communication-deborahk

Please check it and see if there is something different from what you are doing.

One thing to check: are you registering the service multiple times?

For example, you have the service correctly registered here:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LaCasesSelectionService {
```

Are you also registering the service using the `[providers]` array in the module or a component? If so, remove it.

EDIT:
And a side note:

```js
  event.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '')
  // Or to replace all occurrences
  // Use replaceAll if available, otherwise
  // event.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '')
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts to make the example and answer it. I have resolved it actually importing in different way. Instead of importing wholepath of the library component i imported just module name . That is Worked!